# Dockerfile cannot find executable script (no such file or directory)

Tags: docker, shiny-server

I'm writting a Dockerfile in order to create an image for a web server (a shiny server more precisely). It works well, but it depends on a huge database folder (`db/`) that it is not distributed with the package, so I want to do all this preprocessing while creating the image, by running the corresponding script in the Dockerfile.

I expected this to be simple, but I'm struggling figuring out **where** my files are being located within the image.

This repo has the following structure:

```
Dockerfile
preprocessing_files
configuration_files
app/
    application_files
    db/
        processed_files
```

So that `app/db/` does not exist, but is created and filled with files when `preprocessing_files` are run.

The Dockerfile is the following:

```
# Install R version 3.6
FROM r-base:3.6.0

# Install Ubuntu packages
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y \
    sudo \
    gdebi-core \
    pandoc \
    pandoc-citeproc \
    libcurl4-gnutls-dev \
    libcairo2-dev/unstable \
    libxml2-dev \
    libxt-dev \
    libssl-dev

# Download and install ShinyServer (latest version)
RUN wget --no-verbose https://s3.amazonaws.com/rstudio-shiny-server-os-build/ubuntu-12.04/x86_64/VERSION -O "version.txt" && \
    VERSION=$(cat version.txt)  && \
    wget --no-verbose "https://s3.amazonaws.com/rstudio-shiny-server-os-build/ubuntu-12.04/x86_64/shiny-server-$VERSION-amd64.deb" -O ss-latest.deb && \
    gdebi -n ss-latest.deb && \
    rm -f version.txt ss-latest.deb

# Install R packages that are required
RUN R -e "install.packages(c('shiny', 'flexdashboard','rmarkdown','tidyverse','plotly','DT','drc','gridExtra','fitdistrplus'), repos='http://cran.rstudio.com/')"

# Copy configuration files into the Docker image
COPY shiny-server.conf /etc/shiny-server/shiny-server.conf
COPY /app /srv/shiny-server/
COPY /app/db /srv/shiny-server/app/

# Make the ShinyApp available at port 80
EXPOSE 80

CMD ["/usr/bin/shiny-server"]
```

This above file works well **if** `preprocessing_files` are run in advance, so `app/application_files` can successfully read `app/db/processed_files`. How could this script be run in the Dockerfile? To me the intuitive solution would be simply to write:

```
RUN bash -c "preprocessing.sh"
```

Before the `ADD` instruction, but then `preprocessing_files` are not found. If the above instruction is written below `ADD` and also `WORKDIR app/`, the same error happens. I cannot understand why.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot execute code on the host machine from Dockerfile. `RUN` command executes inside the container being built. You can:

- Copy `preprocessing_files` inside docker container and run `preprocessing.sh` inside the container (this would increase size of the container)
- Create a `makefile`/`build.sh` script which launches `preprocessing.sh` before executing `docker build`

Comment: A solution would be the first suggestion, but this fail again. Do not know if I'm placing the files in the right location, but if I `COPY preprocessing*` /srv/ and `WORKDIR /srv/` before using `RUN bash -c "preprocessing.sh", the same error appears. Cannot figure out why it is not even found, when the folder used in `COPY` and `WORKDIR` is exactly the same.

Comment: I got it! Try `bash preprocessing.sh`. `-c` is to execute a command, so `bash -c "echo 123"` would work. Or you can just `RUN ./preprocessing.sh` if it has executable permissions.

Comment: What an embarrassment. It was in fact that `-c` copy-paste error, you are right.

Comment: However I believe that you shouldn't do preprocessing inside of the container, because you would need to copy every dependency of the preprocessing script inside the container. If `db` is a dependency - it needs to be copied also. And even if you delete the data from the container later the image would not shrink, it would just mark the deleted files as deleted. You can use build stages to manage it: https://docs.docker.com/develop/develop-images/multistage-build/

Comment: @EuGENE Happens to the best of us;)